# Update when the query does not return a single row, in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, window-functions

A beginner question.

*Premise*: I get that the crucial issue here is that there is no inherent order in a SQL table, so that in order to "add" a column to a table I have to specify some key to match. However, I am searching for an elegant solution.

*The problem*:
I want to replace the values of column `V1` with a transformation of `V1` obtained through a window function (which I use to fill `NULL` values with the closest known value of `V1`, ordering by `data`).

Example dataset (please notice I do not have a key to identify rows):

```
create table Tab1(data date, V1 number, val number);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-01-01', 1, 100);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-02-01', 1, 110);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-03-01', 1, 100);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-03-01', 1, 130);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-05-01', NULL, 100);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-06-01', NULL, 100);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-03-01', 2, 110);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-03-01', 2, 105);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-04-01', 2, 190);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-05-01', NULL, 200);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-06-01', NULL, 150);

select * from Tab1;

DATA       V1   val
2000-01-01  1   100
2000-02-01  1   110
2000-03-01  1   100
2000-03-01  1   130
2000-04-01  1   100
2000-05-01      100
2000-06-01      100
2000-03-01  2   110
2000-03-01  2   105
2000-04-01  2   190
2000-05-01      200
2000-06-01      150
```

I want to avoid creating a second table like in

```
  create table Tab2 as
    select A.*, 
    (case when V1 is null 
               then last_value(V1) ignore nulls 
               over (partition by V1 order by data 
               range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
          else V1 
          end) V2
 from Tab1 A;
```

Actually, the window function is still not doing what I want but this is a separate issue (still if you got a solution, it is very much welcome). In the end, what I want is the following, where V1 is replace by its version with the nulls replaced by the closest non missing values:

```
DATA       V1   val 
2000-01-01  1   100
2000-02-01  1   110
2000-03-01  1   100
2000-03-01  1   130
2000-04-01  1   100
2000-05-01  1   100
2000-06-01  1   100
2000-03-01  2   110
2000-03-01  2   105
2000-04-01  2   190
2000-05-01  2   200
2000-06-01  2   150
```

I cannot use `update` since windows functions are not admitted and the subquery with the windows function would retrive multiple rows.

Similarly, a `merge into` statement would not work, as I am unable to give a `on` condition that identifies the single row to match (`data` and `V1` are not sufficient).

Is there a way to just "add" the `V2` to `Tab1` without going through the trouble of creating a new table?

Comment: How adding the same values which are not sufficient to identify a row will help to create an identity?

Comment: added sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

First the good news, which is the answer to your question.

> Similarly, a merge into statement would not work, as I am unable to give a on condition that identifies the single row to match (data and V1 are not sufficient).

You can use `rowid` for this.  So:

```
merge into tab1 t using
( select t1.rowid row_id, 
    (case when t1.V1 is null 
               then last_value(t1.V1) ignore nulls 
               over (partition by null order by data 
               range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
          else t1.V1 
          end) new_V1
 from Tab1 t1
) u
on ( t.rowid = u.row_id )
when matched then update set t.v1 = u.new_v1;
```

Now the bad news.

There is no way to do write a windowing function to do what you want.

Consider these two rows in your input data:

> ```
> DATA       V1   val
> 2000-01-01  1   100
> 2000-02-01  1   110
> 2000-03-01  1   100
> 2000-03-01  1   130
> 2000-04-01  1   100
> 2000-05-01      100   <== this one
> 2000-06-01      100
> 2000-03-01  2   110
> 2000-03-01  2   105
> 2000-04-01  2   190
> 2000-05-01      200   <== and this one
> 2000-06-01      150
> ```

There is nothing about those rows that our logic could use to know that the first should get updated to `V1 = 1` and the second should get updated to `V1 = 2`.  The only thing we have is the order in which you listed them, but that information is not stored in your data model anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. About the 'merge ...', you used a `partition by null` and this ultimately seems to make the query proceed to find the `last_value(V1)` according to just the order in which the data are reported... which is confusing to me given the notion that there is not inherent order in the tables. Wouldn't  `partition by null` retrieve them in random order?

Comment: @Giuseppe No, the order is controlled by the `ORDER BY`.  `PARTITION BY NULL` in this case means: look at _all_ the rows in the result set, order them all by `data` and the give me the last, non-null value for `V1`.  Your way, `PARTITION BY V1` means: look at all the rows in the result set that have the same `V1` at the row I am updating, sort them by `data` and give me the last, non-null value for `V1`.  But, the last, non-null `V1` for the window is the same as for the row you are updating, because the `PARTITION BY V1` window only looks at the rows where V1 is the same as the current row.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation. Another possible workaround using `coalesce` has been suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56941067/3019236.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put it in a different way.

No need to create another table. `WITH` clause will work in this situation.

Use the following query:

```
-- your update query
UPDATE TAB1
SET
    V1 = (
        WITH UPDATED_VAL AS (
            SELECT /*+ materialize */
                A.ROWID   RID,
                ( LAST_VALUE(V1) IGNORE NULLS OVER(
                    PARTITION BY DATE1
                    ORDER BY
                        DATE1
                    RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                ) ) V2
            FROM
                TAB1 A
        )
        SELECT
            V2
        FROM
            UPDATED_VAL
        WHERE
            TAB1.ROWID = UPDATED_VAL.RID
    )
WHERE
    V1 IS NULL
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a84b4904267c4e9ef28a0b889a9607a8)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the issue is that, as I stated in the question, I do not have a row id: the substitution should be based only on the current order of the table (which I recognise it's a messy thing in SQL, but this is the stuff I am dealing with). I will add an example dataset to clarify.

Comment: I added an example in the question, to clarify.