# Oracle SQL, fill missing value with the closest non-missing

Tags: sql, oracle, missing-data, window-functions, lag

I have a dataset in which I want to fill missing values witht the closest non-missing value. I found two elegant solutions in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977267/fill-null-values-with-last-non-null-amount-oracle-sql) question, but I don't understand why they are not working for me.

Table:

```
create table Tab1(data date, V1 number);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-01-01', 1);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-02-01', 1);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-03-01', 1);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-04-01', 1);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-05-01', NULL);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-06-01', NULL);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-03-01', 2);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-04-01', 2);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-05-01', NULL);
insert into Tab1 values (date '2000-06-01', NULL);
select * from Tab1;

DATA       V1
2000-01-01  1
2000-02-01  1
2000-03-01  1
2000-04-01  1
2000-05-01  
2000-06-01  
2000-03-01  2
2000-04-01  2
2000-05-01  
2000-06-01
```

Attempt #1:

```
select A.*, 
    (case when V1 is null then lag(V1 ignore nulls)  
               over (partition by V1 order by V1, data) 
          else V1 
          end) V2
 from Tab1 A;
```

Attempt #2:

```
select A.*, 
    (case when V1 is null 
               then last_value(V1 ignore nulls)
               over (partition by V1 order by data 
               range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)  
          else V1 
          end) V2
 from Tab1 A;
```

Both give me the same unwanted result:

```
DATA       V1   V2
2000-01-01  1   1
2000-02-01  1   1
2000-03-01  1   1
2000-04-01  1   1
2000-03-01  2   2
2000-04-01  2   2
2000-05-01      
2000-05-01      
2000-06-01
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I pointed out in your other, nearly identical question, you lack the information required to differentiate between the two input rows having date `2000-05-01`.  The rows are identical, other than their position in your list (which is not something that we can get from the database).  So, there is no way to assign "1" to one and "2" to the other.  If there were some extra information, you would want to add modify your window function to `... partition by null order by data, this_other_new_column...`.  The `partition by null` instead of `partition by v1` is the key idea you missed, I think.

Comment: Sorry about the almost double posting, but the point of the other question was different and this only incidental.

Comment: Maybe I should remove this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version should work, with a slight tweak:

```
select A.*, 
       coalesce(V1, lag(V1 ignore nulls)  over (order by data)) V2
from Tab1 A;
```

The tweak is to remove the `partition by v1` from the `lag()`.  The `coalesce()` is just my preference for simpler expressions.

The same tweak should work for the second version as well.

Your version doesn't work because the `lag()` value must come from the same partition (or be `null`).  When you have `partition by v1`, you are actually ensuring that `v1` has the same value as in the current row.

Answer (score 0):

Hi or you can try manual create the ignore null solution by refer to my below.  thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/57016373/10562099

1. You need use a 0/1 column to indicate the Null/Non-Null data
2. Then create accumulate summary column to calculate the indicator number in step 1. -now you can see the data already looks like grouped by your non_Null data.
3. As last step, pls use a Max function group by the accumulate sum (in step 2) to populate the data(here is amont) in to empty items.